# How to run a string and get a table that has all the variables that the code created in lua?

Tags: lua

So i'm making my own OS for LIKO-12 and I need to run .lk12 files but i need to have a function to run a string as code and return a table that has all of the variables that code created

Example:

```
function foo()
        return "Hello,"
end

function bar()
        return " World!"
end

hello = foo()..bar()
```

should return a table with 2 functions:
A function called foo that returns "Hello,"
A function called bar that returns " World!"
and a variable called hello that has "Hello, World!"

You should be able to call a function from the code using
`vars["foo"]()` or `vars.foo()`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: so you are saying `hello` should a table with 2 functions after doing `hello = foo()..bar()`?

Comment: foo() and bar() return strings and the .. operator concatenates 2 strings adding them together so hello should have "Hello, World!"

Comment: so what is it you want? what "should return a table with 2 functions"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create or use a global variable it's actually stored in a table called "the environment", or `_ENV` (which is *not* global, it's a local that you get automatically)

So your code:

```
function foo()
        return "Hello,"
end

function bar()
        return " World!"
end

hello = foo()..bar()
```

is really doing:

```
function _ENV.foo()
        return "Hello,"
end

function _ENV.bar()
        return " World!"
end

_ENV.hello = _ENV.foo().._ENV.bar()
```

so if we just set `_ENV` to a new table, and return it, then this is exactly the table you want. You can do this with [`load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) (which is how you run strings) by passing it as the 4th argument. This function will do that:

```
function loadAndReturnEnv(codeString)
    local env = {}
    load(codeString, nil, nil, env)() -- error checking skipped for demonstration
    return env
end
```

However, note that all the usual global stuff like `string.rep`, `table.sort`, `load`, `print` don't exist in this new _ENV. If that's what you want, that's great. But I guess you probably do want them. In that case we can use the metatable `__index` feature, so that if the code looks for something in its _ENV and it's not there, it looks in our (the caller's) _ENV instead.

```
function loadAndReturnEnvWithGlobals(codeString)
    -- note: env is the environment for the code we're about to run
    -- (which will be called _ENV in that code), and _ENV is the environment
    -- of the loadAndReturnEnvWithGlobals function (i.e. the "real" environment)
    local env = {}
    setmetatable(env, {__index=_ENV})
    load(codeString, nil, nil, env)() -- error checking skipped for demonstration
    setmetatable(env, nil) -- set the table back to normal before we return it
    return env
end
```

But wait... the program can now call `print` when you run it, but if it defines a function, that function can't call `print` since we deleted the link back to the real environment after the code returned. So I think the best way to fix that is to leave the environment linked, and just copy the functions etc.

```
function loadAndReturnEnvWithGlobals2(codeString)
    local env = {}
    setmetatable(env, {__index=_ENV})
    load(codeString, nil, nil, env)() -- error checking skipped for demonstration

    local result = {}
    for k,v in pairs(env) do result[k]=v end
    return result
end
```

although this copies the values, so if you have any functions that change the variables, you won't see the changed variables.

Which version you use is up to you. They each have pros and cons.